# Client side changes to be done for configuring SQL Server connection encryption in-transit

Tags: sql-server, encryption

SQL Server instance has force encryption flag enabled and SQL Server has valid certificate imported into SQL instance in SQL configuration manager,

I have seen in the documentation that if the client application doesn't support encryption then the connection will fail if the force encryption flag is enabled. What does this mean? Should the client application string have `encrypt=true` if the force encryption flag is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

If the server has Force Network Encryption enabled, then it does not matter whether the connection string has `encrypt=true` set or not. The server will tell the client that it must use encryption to establish the connection.

If the client does not support encryption and the server requires it, no connection will be established.

Setting `encrypt=true` in the connection string is used when the server has a certificate set up which *allows* encryption to be used, but does not *require* it.

Comment: Can you tell me a situation where client does not support encryption if sql server has force encryption enabled

Comment: @RKPAT It's possible that a client library might not have support for TLS, or only support an old version of TLS. Especially if you're dealing with vendor-supplied code/applications that haven't been updated in a long time.

Comment: if force encryption is enabled on SQL Server, is communication encrypted both the ways i.e from client to server and server to client or is it only one way.

Comment: @RKPAT Encrypting the connection (whether forced or optional and set to `true` in the connection string) encrypts the _whole_ connection. There's no point in doing it one-way.